# Show that an outcome in S to the event $ \bigcup_{i=n}^\infty C_{n}$ if and only if it belongs to all the events $A_{2},A_{2}$...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Show that an outcome in S belongs to the event $ \bigcup_{i=n}^\infty C_{n}$ where $C_{n}=\bigcap_{i=n}^\infty A_{i}$ if and only if it belongs to all the events $A_{2},A_{2}...$ except possibly a finite number of those events.

P.S. This is my first post so I probably did something wrong in posting this.

Comment: Hint: Think about set theory. If $x$ is in that infinite union, then what?

Comment: Yes I think this hint and the more explicit answer User1006 gave both helped me at least with half of it. Does the other side of the proof, if x belongs to all events $ A_{2},A_{2}...$  except possibly a finite number of those events then x is in $\bigcup_{i=n}^\infty C_{n}$, need more effort?

Comment: To other side, just choose the max $m$ that $x\notin A_m$. Then for all $n>m, \:x\in C_n$

Comment: Thank you is there any sort of resolved tag on stack exchange I should hit now?

Comment: Correcting the several typos in your formulas (title and body) would be a plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\omega\in \bigcup_{i=n}^\infty C_{n}$. Then there is a $N>n$ that $\omega\in C_N$. Since $C_{N}=\bigcap_{i=N}^\infty A_{i}$, this means that for all $i\geqslant N, \:\omega\in A_i$. So if $\omega\notin A_i$, then $i<N$, i.e. there are only a finite number of those events $A_i$ that $\omega\notin A_i$ .